# Uploading a file in C# to windows server - how to best set up server & client?

Tags: c#, file-upload, windows-server

I'm completely new to Windows servers and uploading to a server in general, so sorry if this is a rather trivial question.

I want to upload a file from a C# client to a windows server, where the file will be accessible via HTTP. I have full access to the server, I do however need to set it up (IIS already has one site running on localhost). What would be the safest / best way to upload a file to this server (possibly without revealing Username/password), and how would I set the server up? Any links to tutorials are welcome. If I understand correctly, FTP isn't the best way to handle this?

Edit: The application only runs in a controlled environment, so granting the application full read/write access to the server should be no problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options.

If the client doing the uploading is outside your network:

- [HTTP upload](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) using an HTTPS connection.  Require login so that not everyone can upload their own version of the file, or
- SFTP.  You will need third-party SFTP software (a shame Windows still does not include that).  [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) is open source and works fine on Windows.

If the client doing the uploading is in your network:

- [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Robocopy sounds interesting, how would I set up the server for that (and what would be the destination parameter for i.e. www.example.com)? I would, however prefer something like SFTP with ssh keys for authentification, is there something windows-equivalent and/or windows-native?

Comment: Personally, I'd stay away from Robocopy. Using that would mean your client user would have to have direct write access to the directory being uploaded to, and even if that's true now, I wouldn't want to assume that it would always be true - network security groups love messing with AD permissions. I'd stick with HTTPS or SFTP if possible.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that, will edit after this comment:
The application only runs in a controlled environment, possibly on one or two pcs only, so granting full write access to the application is not a problem at all

Comment: Cool, that would definitely be your easiest solution - no programming required, just a batch file or something. Or if you're in a .NET application anyway, `File.Copy` does the same thing - copies using the credentials from the current user.

Comment: @Eric Just a nitpick - FileZilla Server doesn't support SFTP, only FTPS. For SFTP on Windows, I believe you need a separate SSH server, like OpenSSH.

Comment: @JoeEnos: Good catch.  I use FileZilla client for SFTP (OpenSSH running on Linux).  Was actually not aware that the server doesn't implement SFTP.  FTPS is probably sufficient for most people.  I'm not aware of a free SFTP server for Windows, though there are paid alternatives.

Comment: @JoeEnos: Update, apparently there are free options http://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows

Comment: @JoeEnos: Robocopy has its place.  It is very powerful, but of course you have to control your environment sufficiently.  Not everyone is in a large company with external groups that will fiddle with permissions.

Comment: @ederseqi: Robocopy only works if you can access the remote folder using a UNC path (that is, it is in your network not some server on the internet).

Comment: @Eric You mean there are organizations out there where you can actually get stuff done instead of get stuck behind a mile of red tape? That's a little difficult to believe. :)

Comment: @JoeEnos: Yes, they are usually called Startups :-)